# Loading from External SD / Saving to ExtSD

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd, storage

I rooted my device, an Android off-brand tablet, and finally found a way to get all my files onto my 32gb SD card instead of the internal SD. However, it says my apps aren't installed now when I click on their icons. Also, new apps install to the internal SD and not the external, despite changing set-install-location to SD. (Tried to change the set-install-location to ExtSD but wouldn't do it.)

The whole point of  buying that SD card was because the space was so insufficient. It boasted 8gb of space plus a MicroSD jack, but I can only use half that space since it's partitioned, so I'm not going to be moving any of the apps back. There simply isn't space, and I'm not uninstalling apps I need/use often. I'm confident there's a workaround somehow. (Sorry, anything I'm finding on Google is people replying with "move it all back"  basically, and I'm getting annoyed.)

I was thinking either I could have Android just use the 32gb instead of it's own storage, and use the internal storage as "SD", i.e. swapping storage. I don't plan on ever removing the Micro SD, as I said, it was bought for this purpose. If that's not possible, maybe there's something I can do to tell Android, "Hey, all the apps are here"?

Thanks, this is endlessly frustrating!

PS: Using Android 4.4.2